# Не выводит стили на печать

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Использую bootstrap. На некоторых строках таблицы есть определённый стиль.

При выводе на печать таблицы, цвет строки пропадает. Видел много решений данной проблемы, но ничего не сработало. Где-то что-то я делаю не правильно. Подскажите как подправить код. Пробую в хроме.

[пример на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p1zg49aw/15/)

Код JS:

```
function Print() {          
   window.print(); 
}
```

CSS:

```
@page {
   size: landscape;
}

@media print {
* {
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  }
  .noPrintable {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Зачем вам js тут? @media print{ .noPrintable: display:none; }

Comment: @DaemonHK Да, наверное так было бы проще, но это не решает основную проблему. Стиль на некоторых сроках таблицы, которые идут на печать не сохраняется, браузер его выбрасывает.

Comment: Ищите в бутстрапе, видимо при печати все сбрасывается, ибо нефиг, экономьте краску)

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался с проблемой. Помогло переопределение классов стилей bootstrap. (Надеюсь верная формулировка)

В моём случае это класс `table-warning`. Решение для него следующее:

```
.table-warning, .table-warning > td, .table-warning > th {
  background-color: #ffeeba !important;
      -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
}
```

Я сначала пробовал только с одним `table-warning`, но это результата не дало, нужно указывать полный путь. И узнать код цвета.

Если кому интересно, то [вот пример кода](https://jsfiddle.net/p1zg49aw/16/).